# BIRT generate dynamic reports

Tags: birt

I created a report in birt, where I would like to click on one of the data points in the report. Then it should link to a new dynamically generated report, that shows the data from the date where I clicked on the last report.

I got a little .gif for you, to demonstrate what I've already done.
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdWDB.jpg)

I did this by creating two reports. The first one being the graph with the two lines which represent random test data. When I press on one of the rectangles from the graph, a hyperlink gets called, which sends me to the second report. This was done by adding a mouse click interaction on the Y values with a drill-through that directs you to another report.

Here is my problem: I want the 2nd report to dynamically adapt according to the date which I selected on the first report. Like seen in the example .gif. Select 31.07.2017 -> show detail from that date.

I don’t want to create a new report for every single date and manually link every single one of them to the correct date. This would be tedious and with updating, new data every day it would also be impossible to maintain.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I made it work with data set parameters and report parameters.

Details for the answer can be found [HERE](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Frp-HowToDefineADataSetParameter.html)

All I had t do is define a paramater and pass the values from my report 1 to my report 2 via the parameter and its working!